# Dynamic select in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I want to do something like this:

```
sql_str := 'select ';    
if (user_input = 1) then
    sql_str := sql_str || 'a.col1 from tb1 a';
else
    sql_str := sql_str || 'a.col1, b.col2, b.col3 from tb1 a, tb2 b';

execute sql_str
```

I don't have much, not to say any, experience with Oracle's procedures, functions, etc.

I'm having trouble to find out how to create a procedure (or function) in Oracle to perform the above code.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Read up on EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

Comment: There are a lot of questions tagged `[oracle]+[dynamic-sql]`. Perhaps if you checked out a couple of answers you would find the clues you need. [Find them here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D+dynamic-sql)

Comment: I have read some other questions, but still couldn't solve my problem. I will try again, though.

Comment: `I'm having trouble to find out how to create a procedure (or function)` - refer to the official Oracle documentation, it's verfy good: [Developing Stored Subprograms and Packages](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TDDDG/tdddg_subprograms.htm#TDDDG40000)  and [PL/SQL Subprograms](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#GUID-13BEBBEC-02D4-48E8-A059-DFEAC4751A3B)

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve - what do you want to do with the results of the query? If you do need a procedure/function, what will call it and what will *that* do with the results?

Comment: I just need to retrieve the data. It would be like a view, but I depend on the user input not to make unnecessary joins. For example, when the user selects Option 1, I should project only table 1's data, but if he selects Option 2, I should project also table 2's data, so for Option 1 I don't need to do a JOIN. There will be many multi-select options, so creating many VIEWS is not a good choice.

Comment: @vinicius Typically the procedure would return a dynamic cursor but that cursor would be executed by the application.  Do you really need to execute and store the results in PL/SQL?  That can be done but it's unusual and difficult and depends on exactly how the data will be stored and processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are not returning any value we have to go for procedure. Although use case is not clear.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dyn_sql_query (user_input IN NUMBER)
    IS
       sql_str VARCHAR2 (500) := 'SELECT ';
    BEGIN
       IF (user_input = 1) 
       THEN sql_str := sql_str || 'a.col1 from tb1 a';
       ELSE sql_str := sql_str || 'a.col1, b.col2, b.col3 from tb1 a, tb2 b';
       END IF;
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_query;
    END;
```

Here is very basic script for function (notice `RETURN`) that accepts table name and returns number of rows.

```
 CREATE FUNCTION count_rows (table_name IN VARCHAR2)
       RETURN PLS_INTEGER   // 
    IS
       sql_query VARCHAR2 (500) := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || table_name;
       ret_val PLS_INTEGER;
    BEGIN
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_query INTO ret_val;
       RETURN ret_val;
    END;
```

Comment: The function is close to what I need, but instead of returning one single value (the count), I need several columns, such as a regular query. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, why not your can change SQL query as you like. In that case you need to collect to record type for example 
`ret_val [schema].tablename%ROWCOUNT` which will reflect result set row.

Comment: I've searched a bit more. With your answer and other information I've found, I got what I wanted, so I'm accepting your answer. Thank you for your help, and also the other users.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Your Example, Here is One Approach to Dynamic SQL**

As others have indicated, there are many examples of dynamic sql on Stack Exchange.

The documentation is very good on this [subject](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#LNPLS01102).  I like the `using` clause which makes the dynamic sql more extensible.

**In practice, the dynamic sql does something: select ... into, a procedural call, dml, dcl.**

```
SCOTT@dev>declare
  2  user_input number(1) :=1;
  3  sql_str varchar2(1000);
  4  begin
  5  
  6  sql_str := 'select ';    
  7  if (user_input = 1) then
  8  --    sql_str := sql_str || 'a.col1 from tb1 a';
  9      sql_str := sql_str || '''1'' from dual';
 10      dbms_output.put_line(sql_str);
 11  else
 12  --    sql_str := sql_str || 'a.col1, b.col2, b.col3 from tb1 a, tb2 b';
 13      sql_str := sql_str || '''2'' from dual';
 14      dbms_output.put_line(sql_str);
 15  end if;
 16  execute immediate sql_str;
 17  end;
 18  /
select '1' from dual

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SCOTT@dev>declare
  2  user_input number(1) :=2;
  3  sql_str varchar2(1000);
  4  begin
  5  
  6  sql_str := 'select ';    
  7  if (user_input = 1) then
  8  --    sql_str := sql_str || 'a.col1 from tb1 a';
  9      sql_str := sql_str || '''1'' from dual';
 10      dbms_output.put_line(sql_str);
 11  else
 12  --    sql_str := sql_str || 'a.col1, b.col2, b.col3 from tb1 a, tb2 b';
 13      sql_str := sql_str || '''2'' from dual';
 14      dbms_output.put_line(sql_str);
 15  end if;
 16  execute immediate sql_str;
 17  end;
 18  /
select '2' from dual

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

With my example as people have commented, a simple `select` statement usually does not make sense (no one does this in practice).

One can see that my dynamic sql is parsed by looking at `v$sql` which shows statistics on the shared sql area:

```
APPS@dev>SELECT
      2      sql_id
      3  FROM
      4      v$sql
      5  WHERE
      6          1 = 1
      7      AND (
      8              sql_text = 'select ''1'' from dual'
      9          OR
     10              sql_text = 'select ''2'' from dual'
     11      ) AND
     12          parsing_schema_name = 'SCOTT';
    SQL_ID         
    -------------
    27q1fj58cnz0k  
    c9bw73fh2ay8d
```

---

### addendum based on comments

As Alex cited, the documentation indicates that a select statement without an `into` clause does not get executed.  It is at least parsed and can be seen in the shared sql area, v$sql.

Here is my example with the `into` clause.

```
APPS@dev>DECLARE
  2      user_input   NUMBER(1) := 1;
  3      sql_str      VARCHAR2(1000);
  4      v_val        VARCHAR2(1);
  5  BEGIN
  6      sql_str := 'select ';
  7      IF
  8          ( user_input = 1 )
  9      THEN
 10  --    sql_str := sql_str || 'a.col1 from tb1 a';
 11          sql_str := sql_str || '''1'' from dual';
 12      ELSE
 13  --    sql_str := sql_str || 'a.col1,b.col2,b.col3 from tb1 a,tb2 b';
 14          sql_str := sql_str || '''2'' from dual';
 15      END IF;
 16  
 17      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_str INTO
 18          v_val;
 19      dbms_output.put_line(sql_str || ' => ' || v_val);
 20  END;
 21  /
select '1' from dual => 1


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: In your example [the query statements are never executed, since you don't have an *into*
 clause](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/executeimmediate_statement.htm#GUID-C3245A95-B85B-4280-A01F-12307B108DC8__GUID-03324D0E-5267-42B9-98BE-8325F9213352). but then the OP hasn't said what they want to do with the results...

Comment: @Alex Poole Yes, I agree that a `select` statement on its own does not make sense.  I think a demonstration of `select ... into` would be better. I read the link and noticed that the `select` statement should not execute.  It is strange that the statement would then show-up in the v$sql.

Comment: @PatrickBacon Wouldn't the SQL first have to be parsed and evaluated to determine that it didn't need to execute? Wouldn't that be why it shows up in v$sql? If it were then repeated, Oracle can look to V$SQL and know that execution is not required.

Comment: @Brian Leach That sounds reasonable.

Comment: The execute count actually is incremented each time the block is run; but note that the fetch count is not. With something like the example shown in the docs, you can see that side-effects (like sequence incrementing) do not occur. Anyway, only mentioned it because there have been a few questions here where people are confused about where the results went (nowhere!).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it helps you but you can create a procedure something like below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_Ali (user_input IN VARCHAR2(2))
IS
   sql_str      VARCHAR2(1000):= 'select ';
   user_input   VARCHAR2(2) := '1';

BEGIN

IF  user_input = '1' THEN 

BEGIN

sql_str := sql_str||'a.col1 from tb1 a';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_str;

dbms_output.put_line (sql_str) ;
END;

ELSE

BEGIN

sql_str := sql_str||'a.col1, b.col2, b.col3 from tb1 a, tb2 b';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_str;

dbms_output.put_line (sql_str) ;
END;

END IF;

END;
```